# What stands behind "Data Science"?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I would like to become a data scientist, the person who uses statistical modelling, MLs methods, and other techniques to solve problems. I real good one. I mean the person who fully understands the techniques, and ideas one is using. my question is how can I achieve this deep understanding? Should I take many advanced statistical classes? Or maybe just basic statistics and is enough to understand statistical modeling and deep learning? What is the **core** of being an excellent data scientist? Generally, my dream is to have an interesting and challenging job in business and I'm not sure what path is best for achieving my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Stackexchange is not a forum for generic open ended questions, and you should have read more carefully the instructions given. I suggest to delete or rephrase your question, otherwise you will get more negative votes as time passes.

Anyways, your question actually focuses on "what is Data Science" rather than the way to become a Data Scientist. First of all, there is a confusion between what RND mean by Data Scientist and what employers understand. This can be understood by looking in job announcements where the title Data Scientist may refer to Data Scientists, Data Analysts, Specialised Data Entry, Junior Data Engineers or simply ITs.

Data Science is a generic term for a respectable amount of specialised job titles. Is statistics enough to be a data scientist? No.
Is programming enough to be a data scientist? No.

You need a strong background in statistics, mathematics, math and algorithmic thinking. You need to understand how SQL and NoSQL Databases operate and the basics of MapReduce. You need to know - at least - Python and how to work with Data Science packages (numpy, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn etc) and version control. Finally you need to have broad knowledge of the sector you want to work at, because you cannot create an algorithm to assess risk if you don't have a clue about risk assessment.

However, the problem is the difference from your understanding of "strong background" and an actual strong background. It is a different thing to believe you know how to write scripts and press buttons on ready-to-go sklearn or Keras functions and a completely different story to understand what a convolution network does in the background according to the variables you set. Accuracy is important, but the presentation and reasoning behind it is even more.

Finally, there are much more experienced people in here to correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe there is a all-know data scientist. You cannot be equally proficient and specialised in everything. Some specialise in computer vision or classification, some others in natural language processing... This doesn't mean that a machine learning engineer who works on image classification has no clue about NLP though, but he needs some time to adjust and get experience on that field before climb in that career ladder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I will leave this question as is it, maybe some future readers will benefit from your answer.